# set alpha for bitmap in racket

Tags: bitmap, scheme, racket, transparent, alpha

So, I'm assigning a bitmap image to an object with the function

```
(define (make-enemy-alienship bitmap-target)
  (let ((dc (new bitmap-dc% [bitmap bitmap-target])))
    (send dc draw-bitmap (read-bitmap "alien.bmp") 0 0)))
```

and I'd like the white pixels in the image to be transparent, but I don't feel that the documentation is much help. Should something be done with the mask parameter? Also, how do you know which bitmap will be 'on top'? Should I for example want a background image I'd obviously want it to be on the bottom.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your bitmap does not contain a transparency channel and you want to use the white value for transparency.
There is a better solution, but if you do not want to modify your image files (and stick with `.bmp` with no alpha channel), you can use [`get-argb-pixels`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/bitmap_.html?q=get-argb-pixels#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._racket%2Fdraw..rkt%29._bitmap~25%29._get-argb-pixels%29%29) and [`set-argb-pixels`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/bitmap_.html?q=get-argb-pixels#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._racket%2Fdraw..rkt%29._bitmap~25%29._set-argb-pixels%29%29) to modify the alpha channel to 1 when the pixel is white (255, 255, 255).

Another possibility is to save your images in `png` format while setting the background color to white (btw, I recommend using a less common color, like purple, otherwise you won't be able to use white pixels in your images). This is done in any decent image editor. Then you can load the `bitmap%` with a "mask" using `png/mask` in the `kind` argument of [`read-bitmap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/Drawing_Functions.html?q=read-bitmap#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fdraw..rkt%29._read-bitmap%29%29).

Yet another approach, which is the one I recommend, is to use image files that have an alpha channel, and load it with `bmp/alpha` (for `.bmp` files). It is common to use the `png` format with an alpha channel (`png` files are like `bmp` files but compressed without loss). You can now use any transparency value, like 50%, which is nice to avoid rough edges.

Regarding which image will be on top, `(send dc draw-bitmap bmp)` will always draw `bmp` on top of what already is drawn in the `dc`, so the way you use it here is fine.

Side comments:

- You should not call `read-bitmap` inside `make-enemy-alienship`, because calling `read-bitmap` is costly (it opens a file, allocates some memory buffer, copies the file in the buffer, and closes the file). Instead, you should save the result of `(read-bitmap "alien.bmp")` into a variable:

  ```
  (define alien-bmp (read-bitmap "alien.bmp"))
  (define (make-enemy-alienship bitmap-target)
    (let ((dc (new bitmap-dc% [bitmap bitmap-target])))
      (send dc draw-bitmap alien-bmp 0 0)))
  ```
- You should use [`define-runtime-path`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=define-runtime-path&q=get-argb-pixels#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fruntime-path..rkt%29._define-runtime-path%29%29) to avoid problems of relative paths depending on your current directory. But this is not your prior concern and you can deal with that later, and focus for now on having nice spaceships on the screen.